# How to populate a combo box in a datagridview as per the selected values in another combobox in datagridview?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, datagridview

May be this is a silly issue. I googled it and did not get any solution. My issue goes like this. I have a datagridview, consisting of 2 Combo boxes. I have 3 tables. Function, Project, and Effort. I am showing the data from the Effort table in the grid. Effort table contains FunctionID, ProjectID and EffortValue. FunctionID and projectID are foreign keys from the respective tables. I have binded the datagridview with Effort table. FunctionID column in the effort table has been changed to combobox, and gets the data from Functions Table. So far so good. Now my issue is I want ProjectID column to be a combobox and get values from Project table, in the same way of functionID column. The catch is I need the projectID to be related to FunctionID - FunctionID is the foreign key of the Project table. Can anybody tell me how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may find the techniques used in this MSDN article helpful with your similar problem:

[Walkthrough: Creating a Master/Detail Form Using Two Windows Forms DataGridView Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y8c0cxey.aspx)